# Can Inject (@EJB) Bean in method of other Bean Session(Remote or Local) class

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I'm a newbie to EJB. I want to know is can inject EJB in method of other bean session, if not why? as code below:

```
@Local
interface car {
    public void drive();
}

@Stateless
public class Toyota implements Car {
   @Override
   public void drive() {
       @EJB 
       Color color;
       ...
   }
}
```

The code example is welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should read some basics about Java EE/EJB before asking everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cant inject into method. You may only use `@EJB` at class level, field or setter like this:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name="myBeanRef", beanInterface=MyBean.class)   // this creates only reference - you will need to initialize it for example via initialConetxt.lookup()
public class EJBTests{
    @EJB (name=”ejb/bean1”)  // this injects bean named ejb/bean1
    MyBean1 bean1;

    MyBean2 bean2;

    ....
    @EJB (name="ejb/bean2")   // this injects bean using setter method
    public void setEcho(MyBean2 bean2) {
       this.bean2 = bean2;
    }
}
```

For more details check `7.1 @EJB – injecting an EJB` from the [EJB 3.1 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `@EJB` `@Target` is defined like this:

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD})
```

and `@Inject` `@Target` is defined like this:

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD })
```

That means that annotation can only be used with listed element types. From Javadoc of `@Target` annotation:

> Indicates the kinds of program element to which an annotation type is
>   applicable.

You should have `LOCAL_VARIABLE` as an ElementType in order to be able to inject it as a local variable of a method.

If you read more about EJBs you will actually find out, that there is a reason for that, as it would be impossible for a container to manage local variables.